# Bitlocker Drive cannot save files on this drive

Tags: read-only, drive, bitlocker

I have a freshly installed Windows 2008 R2 Server with a C drive containing the operating system and d drive as a normal data drive. Ive turned on encryption on the d drive using Bitlocker. The encryption processed all the files and completed successfully. On reboot however when i unlock the drive with the password i used to encrypt it, it unlocks the drive ok and i can access the files but it states:

**You cannot save files on this drive.
Your system administrator has blocked you from saving files on this drive because it has been unlocked using a password. To save files on this drive, unlock it using another method such as a smart card.**

The drive is now accessible but all the files are read only. Am i missing something? What do i need to do to get read/write access to the files again?

PS. This is the second time Ive reformatted and encrypted the drive thinking it was a one off problem. Please note that the server is on a windows AD domain.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem by creating a group policy object with the following setting **disabled**.

1. Run gpedit.exe
2. Computer Configuration/Policies/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/BitLocker Drive Encryption/Fixed Data Drives/Deny write access to fixed drives not protected by BitLocker